# CSS z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index

I have the following setup on 2 div tags:

```
<div id='div1' style='position: absolute; z-index: 2;'>

</div>
<div id='div2' style='z-index: 999;'>

</div>
```

The problem is tha the second div tag contains a link which is not clickable, meaning that the intiail div tag (or DIV1) is on top of it preventing me from being able to click div2.

I can't find a fix for this after messing with it for some time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property only works on positioned elements. So you will need to, for example, assign `position: relative;` to your `div2`.

Comment: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/